# cannot allocate vector of size xxx even after upgrading server instance

Tags: r

I could use some troubleshooting advice. I'm trying to use the `block()` function of the `{blocktools}` package on a dataframe with only 45k obs and 14 variables (4 of which I'm trying to block on). I got an error that R could not allocate vector of size X, so I upgraded the AWS instance which doubled the memory. I restarted the instance and tried running again.

I'm still getting the error and can't figure out why seeing as I doubled the memory. Does R on Linux require me to say how much memory should be available? Any other troubleshooting tips?

FWIW, I'm running `rm(list=ls())`, loading only the dataframe I need, and throwing in `gc()` for good measure.

What else can I try?

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: I solved my immediate problem by breaking the task into batches, but my original question still remains. The SO advice I found for other people asking about this error suggested adding more memory.